# "Folding" a SVG region

Tags: svg

While writing a widget for displaying some data, I came across the idea that it would be useful to be able to "fold" a horizontal region of a SVG image, so that the content within the defined region is collapsed.

E.g. given an image that looks like this

```
* 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 *
*                     *
* ---     ----------- *
* # #### ############ *
* %%%%%       %%%%%%% *
*                     *
***********************
```

a folding of 3-4 would end up looking like

```
* 1 2 5 6 7 8 9 0 *
*                 *
* --------------- *
* # ############# *
* %%%     %%%%%%% *
*                 *
*******************
```

Does anyone have any thoughts as to how this could be best implemented? Possibly rendering onto one "canvas" that is then referenced via a set of uses and masking/clip-path? I'm trying to make this work with as low a memory footprint as possible too, so that it doesn't have too much overhead on a 1st gen iPad.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is probably to just move your vector space using a few nested svg elements.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%">
    <!--
    Move over to the right side of our box.
    Now the graphic is pinned to the x=100% side of the graphic.
    -->
    <svg x='100%' overflow='visible'>
        <!--
        Then move backwards however many pixels you want.
        Just change the x property...
        -->
        <svg x='-500' overflow='visible'>
            <text y='20'>Blah ditty blah dee blah. SVG for the win!</text>
        </svg>
    </svg>
    <!-- This element stays pinned to the left in the original svg box.-->
    <rect fill="#333" fill-opacity='.5' width="200" height="100%" mask="url(#m)"/>
</svg>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ddknoll/Ee4Aq/